# How to do pagination in wordpress page that contain mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pagination

I have one wordpress page in that I want to add pagination code. Because of mysql query the data in page is dynamic so I searched on google [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-pagination-to-a-custom-select-query) but as I'm new in wordpress don't know what is WP-PageNavi plugin and how to use it. Please suggest me how to use it or any simpler way to do this.

My code is:

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:200% !important" name="myTab">  
<thead>  
<tr> 
 <th>Sr.No</th> 
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>College Name </th>
 <th>Passout Year</th>
 <th>Branch</th>
 <th>Email ID </th>
 <th> Phone No.</th>
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
    
    [hi_php] 
     
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("wp");
    
     $query = mysql_query("select id,value from wp_crf_entries where value like '%Alumini%' ")or die(mysql_error());
     
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))  
     {
    $users = maybe_unserialize($row['value']);
    echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['firstname_1'];   
      echo "&nbsp;".$users['lastname_2'] ."</br>";
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['collegename_4'] ;
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['passoutyear_7'] ;
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['branch_8'] ;
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['user_email'] ;
    echo "</td><td>";
      echo $users['contactno_10'] ;
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
     }
     
   [/hi_php]
          
</tbody>  
 </table>
```

Comment: google wp query there is loads of material on pagination if you use wpquery otherwise you need your own function

Comment: @David - can you explore it in little-bit detail as I did pagination in php, mysql but in wordpress it's more difficult to me. Can you please give some advise?

Comment: sorry just read the mysql there. You are not using wp posts for the query so you can just use standard pagination, e.g. `URL?vpage=3` etc. (avoid use of page / paged query vars as wp uses them)